# How can I attach closet shelving supports where there are no studs,

Tags: closet, support

I would like to put in some shelves similar to what is in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTIQxX6MrHs) in a hallway closet.  The length of each shelf is around 42".

I planned on using the 2x2s for support per the video.  The only problem is that the back wall where the longer 2x2 would be supporting the shelf has no studs.  The drywall is directly against the cinderblock firewall between my unit and my neighbor's (I live in a condo).  I assume it is attached via construction adhesive because that is what was in my half bath as well.

My question - could I just screw the back 2x2 at each end to the studs in the side walls of the closet and maybe throw some construction adhesive between the 2x2 and the drywall for added support?

The side supports will be screwed into studs at each end and are approximately 12" in length.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2x2 glued to sheetrock won't support any weight.

Instead, go through the sheetrock and install a masonry anchor in the cinderblock. Put a screw through the 2x2->sheetrock->cinderblock

Comment: In general, it is ok to drill into cinderblock?  If so, I think this is probably the safest bet.  I don't want to have to repair these a year from now because they are sagging or they break.

Comment: Fine, but use a masonry bit and go slowly.

Comment: If you have access to a hammer drill, it will speed up the drilling process quite a bit. The problem with a standard drill is that the masonry bit will overheat and get dull quickly.

Comment: I wouldn't use a hammer drill on an interior cinderblock wall, as it might blow a bigger hole in the cinderblock than your neighbor would like.